# WiX installer InstallCondition always evaluating to False

Tags: wix

I have a bootstrapper project where in I want to conditionally install one of my pre requisites software. I am using the following code to read the version of the software present in system during installation.

```
<Property Id="OPENTAPVERSION">
    <DirectorySearch Id="OpenTapDllVersion" 
                     Path="C:\Program Files(x86)\Keysight\TestAutomation\OpenTap.dll">
        <FileSearch Name="OpenTap.dll" 
                    MinVersion="9.18.4.9"/>
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Then under my msipackage element this is what I have done.

```
<Variable Name="OpenTapVer" Value="9.18.5.0" Type="version" />

<MsiPackage Vital="yes"
            Visible="yes"
            InstallCondition="OPENTAPVERSION = OpenTapVer"
         
        SourceFile="..\..\..\output\OpAInstaller\bin\$(var.Configuration)\ITS.OpenTapWixSetup.msi"
            DisplayName="Install OpenTAP"/>
```

What I want is to conditionally install version 9.15.5.0 and above only. Am I doing something wrong during the version comparison? Instead of having a variable "OpenTapVer" to hold the string 9.18.5.0, I tried simply using "v9.18.5.0" but it still evaluates to false no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

`Property` element is used in an MSI and `Variable` is used in a bundle. Since you are in a `Bundle`, you need to write your search in terms of a `Variable`.